# Typescript Discord and JSON

Tags: typescript, discord

I am writing a Discord bot with Typescript. I want to save something about Discord bot with JSON. I looked another pages and I write this to the code

```
import save from 'save.json'
```

I am getting a error in 'save.json' part on the code [image]. I enabled "resolveJsonModule" but it isn't reading the json file. The error is "Cannot find module 'save.json' or its corresponding type declarations." That's it.

Comment: You should use a relative import instead because it might think `save.json` is a module you installed from npm.

Comment: I found the solution, the solution is just './save.json'

Comment: Instead of providing your code in an image, it would be better in the future if you inserted them in a codeblock. To create a code block, all you have to do is add three backticks/tilde around your code

Comment: What does your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` look like? I import values from json in typescript by, for example: `import { value } from './file.json';`